# Buffer 200 degrees (without north, northeast and -west) for polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, buffer, shadow

For shading analysis I buffer my objects (buildings, trees, etc. They are polygons) with a 40 m buffer.

Since in the northern hemispehre the sun is never shinning from the north I thought about a buffer without the southern part i.e. maybe just 200° (east, south and west)

So instead of this:

[image]

rather something like  that:

[image]

There is no shade in southern area of the polygon because the sun is never shining from the north.

How to do this?

Comment: Shadows tend to fall in the direction **opposite** of the sun. So... maybe flip your shadows around.

Comment: yeah, you are right of course!

Comment: There are specialized tools for such tasks . Did you habe a Look what Grass offers?

Comment: not yet. no experience with GIS outside of QGIS. But I will look it up

Comment: Grass tools are available inside QGIS

Comment: Not really clear what you mean by buffer just 200 degrees - can you add a screenshot how the result should look like?

Comment: see solution below. However, I'm not sure if what you intend to do makes sense in a real world setting, you should think about what you want to achieve. I guess your idea of a 200 degrees buffer does not produce any meaningful results. And, by the way: you still have the shadows flipped in your screenshot as if sun would shine from the south. So please again: reflect about what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

With QGIS expressions, you can achieve that (change buffer distance `100` and `300` and degrees `0` and `200` to fit your use case):

```
intersection (
    buffer ($geometry, 100),
    wedge_buffer( 
        centroid ($geometry),
        0,
        200,
        300
    )
)
```

*A regular buffer (light blue) around the buildings (yellow) is intersected with a wedge buffer (light red) to produce the result you're looking for: dark blue buffer polygons:*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A better approach then a 200 degrees buffer would be:

1. Create a horizontal line in the south
2. Determine the surface of the buildings oriented towards this line (towards south), creating a polygon from the south line to the westmost and the easternmost points of the building
3. Create the intersection of this polygon with a buffer around your buildings.

*Black line = south line (step 1); blue: polygon (step 2), red: intersection = the solution (step 3):*
[image]

You can achieve that using QGIS expressions:

```
with_variable (
    'south',
    geometry (get_feature_by_id ('south', 1)),
    difference (
        intersection (
            buffer ($geometry, 30),
            make_polygon ( 
                make_line (
                    closest_point (
                        $geometry,
                        extend (
                            make_line (
                                closest_point(
                                    @south,
                                    make_point (
                                        x_max (bounds ($geometry)), 
                                        y_min( bounds( $geometry))
                                    )
                                ),
                                make_point (
                                    x_max (bounds( $geometry)), 
                                    y_min (bounds( $geometry))
                                )
                            ),
                            0,
                            1000
                        )
                    ),
                    closest_point(
                        $geometry,
                        extend (
                            make_line (
                                closest_point(
                                    @south,
                                    make_point (
                                        x_min (bounds( $geometry)), 
                                        y_min (bounds( $geometry))
                                    )
                                ),
                                make_point (
                                    x_min (bounds( $geometry)), 
                                    y_min (bounds( $geometry))
                                )
                            ),
                            0,
                            1000
                        )
                    ), 
                    start_point (@south), 
                    end_point(@south)
                )
            )
        )
    ,
    $geometry
))
```